# What does modulus do in this line?

Tags: c#, modulo

I just need to understand why does minutes%60 works.
this code is supposed to get minutes input and tell you how many days,hours,minutes can fit into it (there are 1440 minutes in a day).

```
     using System;

 public class Time
 {
     public static void Main()
     {
         int minutes = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
         int days = (minutes/1440);
         int hours = (minutes%1440)/60;
         Console.WriteLine("days: " + days + " hours: " + hours + " minutes: " + minutes%60);

     }
 }
```

Comment: Why would you expect it *not* to work? Come up with test cases, and step through them.

Comment: In `minutes%60` % is reminder operator. Please read about it to get better understanding of above code https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-

Comment: @ITMan: _remainder_, actually, which isn't quite the same :)

Comment: Right it's a typo...

Comment: @JonSkeet it's not that i expect it not to work i just want to know how it works in that case.

Comment: How it works in *what* case? Again, thinking of specific values would be useful. What does it do when `minutes` is 30? What about when it's 185? What about when it's 1450? (Do you need to handle negative values?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of `y = minutes%1440` this way

```
int x = (minutes/1440);
int y = minutes - 1440*x
```

The value of `y` holds the remainder of the division `minutes/1440`

Answer (score 2):

% is the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation):

> In computing, the modulo operation returns the remainder or signed remainder of a division, after one number is divided by another (called the modulus of the operation).

```
minutes % 60
```

You can think of this as repeatedly removing 60 from minutes until a total of less than 60 is left.
When the snippet is evaluated it will remove all extra minutes
leaving a total of less than 1 hour (60 minutes) of remaining minutes.

Comment: @Daevin yeah i'm new here so i didn't know, thank you!